# Using innerHTML breaks the keyup function

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, onkeyup

So I have a text field:

```
number of weeks <div id = "weekcount"><input type="text" id="numweeks" name="numweeks" value="" class = "dialog_inputfield" /></div><br />
```

And a Javascript function that checks if the value changes in that text field at any point:

```
$('#numweeks').keyup(function(event) {
        var date = $('#datepicker').val();
        var numWeeks = $('#numweeks').val();
        change(calculate(date, numWeeks));
});
```

And that works fine. But I used innerHTML to change the div with the id "weekcount" to contain another textfield, and I changed it back to the original text field with:

```
document.getElementById('weekcount').innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="numweeks" name="numweeks"  value="" class = "dialog_inputfield" />'
```

After that the keyup no longer works, even though the id is the same as it was before. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently binding directly to the DOM element, but that gets replaced by your `innerHTML` assignment, thereby also losing the event binding (it's a new DOM element).

What you want is to use a delegated ("live") event. Have a look at the [jQuery `on` function](http://api.jquery.com/on/), it unifies nicely all event handling patterns.

```
$('#weekcount').on('keyup', '#numweeks', function(event) {
        var date = $('#datepicker').val();
        var numWeeks = $('#numweeks').val();
        change(calculate(date, numWeeks));
});
```

Comment: Good answer. Been using `on` for all delegates these days